# SensioLabsInsight can't connect to the database

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I'm trying to validate my Symfony 3 project but I get an error with composer scripts:

> SensioLabsInsight was not able to install your Composer dependencies. If you need to customize files or run commands to make it work, you can edit your SensioLabsInsight project configuration to override the default "pre_composer_script" and/or "post_composer_script" settings.

Here is the error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                             
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:      

    [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
    An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused    

    [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    

    [PDOException]                                                               
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I do not know why SensioLabsInsight needs to connect to the database.

Comment: Have you already found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

After clearing the cache, Symfony tries to boot the kernel. That includes connecting to the database.

> When installing your project's dependencies, the composer install
>   command is executed. In turn, this command executes the cache:clear
>   command, which tries to **boot the kernel** of your application.

https://insight.sensiolabs.com/help/#how-can-i-connect-to-a-database

I had the same problem and decided to use an in-memory `pdo_sqlite` database in my test environment (which I was already using somewhere else), but you can also use MongoDB, Redis, or Memcached.

Comment: It's a fix but not the real solution. If you have to switch between two types of databases, you could have problem, sometimes...

Comment: That's right, it's not a full solution. The problem is that you shouldn't connect to a database in the first place in an environment like SensioLabs Insight. The solution would be Symfony not requiring a database connection at cache:clear. Feel free to create a pull request ;). Meanwhile, use this workaround.

Comment: Has someone came up with a definitive solution?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me, apprently the issue affects DBAL 2.5

So you have to add the server version in config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    server_version: 5.6
```

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/351)

Comment: This doesn't help, since there is no database server on SensioLabsInsight's server.